# C# .Net Core problem with create FileStream (docker on mapped volume from Mac OS host)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, macos

My application executing in docker container.

Host is MacOs

Container is Linux

Running in debug

In docker-compose I mapped volume

```
volumes:
      - /Users/blabla/Temp:/temp
```

In this case time to time when I try to create FileStream I got exception **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**

StackTrace:

> at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)\n   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)\n   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)\n   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)\n   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)\n   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)

```
var mappedFolderPath = "/temp/testFile.png";
var exist = System.IO.File.Exists(mappedFolderPath);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      using var streamForTest = System.IO.File.OpenRead(mappedFolderPath);
      var justForTest = streamForTest.Length;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        **// Happen after 3-4 times.**
        var exception = ex;
    }
 }
```

But in case when I copy file to output directory I dont have this exception

*.csproj fragment*

```
...
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="StaticContent\testFile.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

```
var root = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var path = Path.Combine(root, "StaticContent", "testFile.png");
var exist = System.IO.File.Exists(path);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      using var streamForTest = System.IO.File.OpenRead(mappedFolderPath);
      var justForTest = streamForTest.Length;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        **// Never to happen.**
        var exception = ex;
    }
 }
```

In two cases System.IO.File.Exists(path) = true

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're using a temporary folder. Are you sure nothing deletes files in it? It doesn't make sense for a file to exist in one iteration and disappear after 4 unless something actually deleted it

Comment: You call `File.Exists(mappedFolderPath);` outside the loop but as you say, the file disappears 3-4 iterations *after* that. I suspect if you check inside the loop you'll see the file no longer exists

Comment: It is static content and it's program for test on my computer, file in the place it 100%. Both of this code sample execute in one time.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: After restarting docker the problem is solved.